# Css style sheet for a specific Id from database?

Tags: css

The following code is getting our categories from our database.
We have a categorie named: SALE! But all the colours all the same..
My question is, how can I "say" to my .css that he only needs to change the colour of: SALE!
The id of sale is 0 and, Apple 1, Samsung 2 etc...

```
 <div id="maincontainer">
        <div id="menu">

            <h3><center><b>Categorieën</center></b></h3>
            <hr width="100%">
             @Html.Action("CategoryList", "Categorie")
        </div>
```

So:

> Categorieeen
>
> 1. SALE! <<< colour orange
> 2. Apple
> 3. Samsung

So far:

```
div#menu{float:left;width: 130px; min-height:inherit;background-color: #ffffff; border-width: .1em; border-style:solid; border-color: #0404B4; text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0px; }
```

but as i expected, the whole menu changes instead of the sale! only..

Comment: `#0 {css here}`. Side notes: `<center>` was deprecated ages ago so try not to use it and also try not to use IDs that begin with numbers for greatest compatibility.

Comment: 1. Never stard ID's and Classes with numbers, the css won't read it. 2. Try to apply a unique class to the container and style it different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change 1 out of a menu/model thing with css instead of a whole model/menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900238/how-to-change-1-out-of-a-menu-model-thing-with-css-instead-of-a-whole-model-menu)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be if you could add a class or ID to that particular row, when you generate the list, and then use that as selector for your CSS rule, but if that isn't an option, you would have to resort to other options.

It is a bit hard to say for certain with the example you've given, but if "Sale!" always is the first item in a list, then you could make use of the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3afirst-child) pseudo class and construct a CSS-rule like this:

```
li:first-child {
   color: #fc0;
}
```

To make it more specific, to only match the list containing categories, you could make the rule more specific by also adding some of the parents to the selector, e.g. `#menu li:first-child`

Answer (score 0):

Class and id names cannot begin with a number, so something to this effect would work:

```
#category_0 {
    // styles
}

<li id="category_0">SALE!</li>
```

Alternately, you could use the category name as the id (as long as you strip out invalid characters and whitespace):

```
#SALE {
    // styles
}

<li id="SALE">SALE!</li>
```

Comment: "id names cannot begin with a number". They can in HTML5.