# How to change 1 out of a menu/model thing with css instead of a whole model/menu?

Tags: css

The following code is getting our categories from our database.
We have a categorie named: SALE! But all the colours all the same..
My question is, how can I "say" to my .css that he only needs to change the colour of: SALE!
The id of sale is 0 and, Apple 1, Samsung 2 etc...

```
 <div id="maincontainer">
        <div id="menu">

            <h3><center><b>Categorieën</center></b></h3>
            <hr width="100%">
            <h7><a href="/Categorie/cat/0">SALE!</a></h7><br />
            <h7><a href="/Categorie/cat/1">Htc</a></h7><br />
            <h7><a href="/Categorie/cat/2">Apple</a></h7><br />            
        </div>
  </div>
```

So:

> Categorieeen
>
> 1. SALE! <<< colour orange
> 2. Apple
> 3. Samsung

So far:

```
div#menu{float:left;width: 130px; min-height:inherit;background-color: #ffffff; border-width: .1em; border-style:solid; border-color: #0404B4; text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0px; }
```

but as i expected, the whole menu changes instead of the sale!

Comment: We are not interested in this case in your backend programming, but in the resulting frontend HTML code. Could you paste that?

Comment: I could paste a picture but its not that hard to see tho, i mean, its like i typed under the code: Everthing remains the same colour but i wanna change the first one

Comment: It's not that hard to edit your code.

Comment: Sorry but i do not no what you mean or what you want me to post..

Comment: In your code you have `@Html.Action("CategoryList", "Categorie")`. This is some server side code and does not matter with this problem. We need to see the __exact__ HTML code, that your server script produces.

Comment: Is this what you mean:See code

Comment: I edited you code to what I mean. What is h7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS3 selector [nth-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp).
If your output is a list then to change the first

element you would need to add:

```
div#menu h7:nth-of-type(1) a {color:#ff0000;}
```

You can check it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rJ4aJ/3/)

'Edited the class to target links inside the list elements

Comment: @Html.ActionLink(Model[i].naam, "Product", "Categorie")

That is the code that shows all my categories, so its a model, can i approach it the same way? or not?

Comment: what does it generate? I assumed it generates a html list. You can change the css code to whatever element your code generates. It's the CSS you have to change not your model

Comment: Yea i understand now, but when i put the code in like you did in the fiddle, the colour remains the same, Its a link, so its blue, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Hmm, I guess there is another class that styles the link. You should override this one